# I wanted to create a table into mysql database using Spring Boot and JPA, but I got some errors when I run it

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Table Server:

```
package com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.model;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.enumerate.Status;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Server {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")

    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "IP Address cannot be empty or null")
    private String ipAddress;
    private String name;
    private String memory;
    private String type;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Status status;
}
```

- Resource:

```
package com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.resource;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.model.Response;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.model.Server;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.service.implementation.ServerServiceImpl;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Map;
import static com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.enumerate.Status.SERVER_UP;
import static java.time.LocalDateTime.now;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/server")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServerResource {
   
    private final ServerServiceImpl serverService;
    private HttpStatus ok;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> getServers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now())
                                .data(Map.of("servers", serverService.list(30)))
                                        .message("Servers retrieved")
                                        .status(ok)
                                        .statusCode(ok.value())
                                        .build()
                                );

    }

    @GetMapping("/ping/{ipAddress}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> pingServer(@PathVariable("ipAddress") String ipAddress) throws IOException {
        Server server = serverService.ping(ipAddress);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now())
                        .data(Map.of("server", server))
                        .message(server.getStatus() == SERVER_UP ? "Ping success" : "Ping failed")
                        .status(ok)
                        .statusCode(ok.value())
                        .build()
        );


    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> SaveServer(@RequestBody @Valid Server server )  {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now())
                        .data(Map.of("server", serverService.create(server)))
                        .message("Server created")
                        .status(CREATED)
                        .statusCode(CREATED.value())
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> getServer(@PathVariable("id") Long id)  {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now())
                        .data(Map.of("server", serverService.get(id)))
                        .message("Server retrieved")
                        .status(ok)
                        .statusCode(ok.value())
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> deleteServer(@PathVariable("id") Long id)  {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now())
                        .data(Map.of("deleted", serverService.delete(id)))
                        .message("Server deleted")
                        .status(ok)
                        .statusCode(ok.value())
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/image/{fileName}", produces = IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public byte [] getServerImage(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "Downloads/images/" + fileName));
    }

}
```

- Service:

```
package com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.service;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.model.Server;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

public interface ServerService {
    Server create(Server server);
    Server ping(String ipAddress) throws IOException;
    Collection<Server> list(int limit);
    Server get(Long id);
    Server update(Server server);
    Boolean delete(Long id);
}
```

- ServerServiceImpl:

```
package com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.service.implementation;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.model.Server;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.repo.ServerRepo;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.service.ServerService;
import com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.service.ServerService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Random;
import static com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.enumerate.Status.SERVER_DOWN;
import static com.elyarmuk.servermanagement.enumerate.Status.SERVER_UP;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class ServerServiceImpl implements ServerService {

    
    private final ServerRepo serverRepo;
    @Override
    public Server create(Server server) {
        log.info("Saving new server: {}", server.getName());
        server.setImageUrl(setServerImageUrl());
        return serverRepo.save(server);
    }

    @Override
    public Server ping(String ipAddress) throws IOException {
        log.info("Pinging server IP: {}", ipAddress);
        Server server = serverRepo.findByIpAddress(ipAddress);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        server.setStatus(address.isReachable(10000) ? SERVER_UP : SERVER_DOWN);
        serverRepo.save(server);
        return server;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Server> list(int limit) {
        log.info("Fetching all servers");

        return serverRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, limit)).toList();
    }

    @Override
    public Server get(Long id) {
        log.info("Fetching server by Id: {}", id);
        return serverRepo.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Server update(Server server) {
        log.info("Updating server: {}", server.getName());
        return serverRepo.save(server);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean delete(Long id) {
        log.info("Deleting server: {}", id);
        serverRepo.deleteById(id);
        return TRUE;
    }

    private String setServerImageUrl() {
        String [] imageNames = {"server1.png", "server2.png", "server3.png", "server4.png"};

        return ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/server/image/" + imageNames[new Random().nextInt(4)]).toUriString();
    }
}
```

- Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerManagementApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(ServerRepo serverRepo) {
        return args -> {
            serverRepo.save(new Server(null, "192.168.1.160", "Ubuntu Linux", "16 GB", "Personal 
           PC", "http://localhost:8080/server/image/server1.png", Status.SERVER_UP));
            serverRepo.save(new Server(null, "192.168.1.58", "Fedora Linux", "16 GB", "Dell 
            Tower", "http://localhost:8080/server/image/server2.png", Status.SERVER_DOWN));
            serverRepo.save(new Server(null, "192.168.1.21", " MS 2008", "32 GB", "Web Server",
            "http://localhost:8080/server/image/server3.png", Status.SERVER_UP));
            serverRepo.save(new Server(null, "192.168.1.14", "Red Hat Enterprise Linux", "64 GB", 
            "Mail Server","http://localhost:8080/server/image/server4.png", Status.SERVER_DOWN));
        };
    }

}
```

- Errors:
  Then after I run the program, I get some errors as follow:
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'serverdb.server' doesn't exist
Any Advise????
Thanks

Comment: The Exception states the problem: Table 'serverdb.server' doesn't exist. The tables need to exist before an app can perform CRUD operations on it. You've obviously setup a database somewhere and specified a serverdb schema be used, but not created the tables, or configured JPA to automatically create the tables (a development feature I would NOT rely on) when it starts.

Comment: I configured that in application.yml : spring:
  datasource:
    password: letmein
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/serverdb
    username: root
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
            format_sql: true
            show-sql: true

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you have created the tables in that database.